# AWS Codebuild - Error in UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS phase: BucketRegionError: incorrect region, the bucket is not in 'us-east-2' region at endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to create the artifact and upload it to s3 bucket in North California using codebuild project in Ohio. But, the final stage of the build is failing with the error "Error in UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS phase: BucketRegionError: incorrect region, the bucket is not in 'us-east-2' region at endpoint". Below I have mentioned the buildspec file. Codebuild project is created to pick the buildspec file from code commit. May I know, how can I add the artifact created from codebuild project in Ohio region to s3 bucket in North California region?

```yaml
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.7
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - pip install --upgrade pip
      - pip install cfn-lint
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - cd ./folder
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file testing.yml --output-template-file testing-packaged-cf.yml --s3-bucket codepipeline-test-bucket --region us-west-1
      - echo $PWD
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo $PWD
artifacts:
  files:
    - testing-packaged-cf.yml
  base-directory: $PWD
```

Answer (score 1):

How about outputting the artifacts to the Ohio region once, and then cross-region replication between the destination S3 bucket (Ohio region) and the S3 bucket in the Northern California region?

Comment: Thanks you Shintaro for your response. Yes that can be done. But I was trying to do the multiple region deployment. I  found out that multiple region deployment is possible by adding multiple action in the deploy stage of  code pipeline .